# How do you customize a Vue Chartkick <line-chart>

Tags: vue.js, chartkick

I have to customize a chart with code structure of something like this:

```
<line-chart :curve="false" :data="pie" :library="Library"></line-chart>    
Library:{
    elements: {
          points: {
                borderWidth: 10
          }
    },
}
```

How should I go about that?

What I need to do is customize the line-chart to something like this;
to change the color of the line and change the design of the points to something circle like. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qrp3.png

Comment: I slightly reworded your question, *guessing* what you intend to ask. Please review my changes and further improve your question. We can't help you, unless you ask a clear, complete question.

Comment: i have added more info, wish it can be understood more! thanks!